# Getting YouTube videos with most views in last 24 hours

Tags: youtube

I have found an example of someone apparently successfully doing this: https://tool.veescore.com/showcase/videos/views?interval=1d, but this only updates once every 5 days. Can anyone suggest how I could request this information manually?

Answer (score -1):

YouTube api request allows you to enter a specifier for published after x time, so you could grab the time 24 hours ago and apply it to.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=viewCount&publishedAfter=2017-10-27T00%3A00%3A00Z&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: I am trying the look at the videos published at any time with the most views in last 24 hours.

Comment: It has both a publishedAfter and publishedBefore so just pick out a date between them